# Setting min and max pool size for ODBC Drivers in Windows

Tags: c#, odbc, connection-pooling, filemaker

I have coded a **C#** application to setup an **ODBC connection** to any ODBC enabled DB.

I have used this application to connect to **FileMaker DB** via ODBC. To achieve better performance, I have enabled the connection pooling option for **FileMaker ODBC Driver** via `ODBC Data Sources -> Connection Pooling`Panel by double clicking the `FileMaker ODBC` Driver and setting the necessary pooling options. However in this setting dialog there exist no place to configure the max and min pool size ( ie. maximum connections in the pool, and minimum connection to be left open in the pool) for  the pool used for the related ODBC driver.

I wonder if there exists any other way to configure the maximum and minimum pool size for a specific (in this case FileMaker ODBC Driver) ODBC driver.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FileMaker ODBC driver does not support connection pooling, there can be a maximum of 50 (when using FileMaker Server) and 9 (when using FileMaker Pro) concurrent ODBC/JDBC connections.

Comment: As far as I know, connection pooling is managed through Microsoft ODBC Data Source Administrator. It is not FM ODBC Driver that supports pooling, it is MS ODBC DS Administrator. Connection pooling can be activated and actually works with FM Databases when observed through Perfmon, however there exists no settings for pool size etc. The only setting is the time for the unused connection to stay in the pool, after that time ODBC DS admin closes (hard disconnect) the connection.